# Does Apple Store support multiple versions of the same application with different allowed countries?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, appstore-approval

I have an app at version 1 that is available to all countries. Let's say that version 2 is now developed, but for some reason, I cannot release version 2 to the EU, yet. Is there a way for me to submit the app to Apple for review, then release this version 2 whilst still having version 1 available to the EU?

Then, let's say, a month later, I am given the "OK" to enable version 2 for the EU. Can I then take version 1 off the app store, and force everyone to upgrade to version 2?

Thanks for any information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This is not possible using Apple iTunes Connect. Apple allows to offer
>   previous version of apps for older iOS devices but not offer previous
>   versions country wise

A simple alternative for you can be to simply manage this from code side.

```
if (device.locale == @"EU") {
   // use version 1 features 
}
else {
   // use version 2 features
}
```

Comment: Can locale be spoofed? Where is it tied to? The country set on the device or the country set on the apple ID?

Comment: set on device, you can also check user language. apple store login can also be spoofed so i dont see this being any different. Both way will have their pro and cons

Comment: I guess there's no way to prevent users in the EU from downloading the new app, either. My situation is one where the new software absolutely cannot be downloaded in a country that it is not authorized before given authorization.

Comment: then you should check user location simply. dont think that can be spoofed. you can also track user IP but i guess they can connect to VPN.